# Dataset is not getting updated

Tags: c#, dataset, ms-access-2007

I have created a dataset, ds and within this dataset I have added a TableAdapter Cust.I have then connected my Customer table in access database to  TableAdapter Cust.For TableAdapter Cust,i have added the query from query builder as "select Cust_ID,Cust_Name from Customer".

So basically, the Cust_ID,Cust_Name in the Customer table in access file is being copied into columns Cust_ID,Cust_Name columns in TableAdapter Cust.
Now ds.Cust is datasource for a table in my rdlc report.

I ran the code once and the table in rdlc report shows the data Cust_ID,Cust_Name as present in Customer table in access file.
But when I add more rows to my Customer table in access file,and i run the code table in rdlc report is NOT showing me the updated data in Customer table in access file.

So im assuming the TableAdapter Cust is not getting updated when I update my Customer table in access file.

How do I update TableAdapter Cust when Customer table in access file is updated(which is the data source for Cust)?

Basically when TableAdapter is not getting updated when its database is updated.
Thanks for any reply in advance.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I solved it.I had two access files with same names .I was updating the wrong access file.Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for your reply,Rufus L